# PL SQL Find Dependencies on Table Field

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, dependencies

I am needing to find all references to a table's field, and I have hundreds of stored procedures to search through. The goal is to find where it is being used in where clauses and add an extra value to the in statement. For example,

`where myTable.Field_X in (1,2,3)`

needs to become

`myTable.Field_X in (1,2,3,4)`.

So I'm curious if there is a system table, like dba_dependencies, or something that I can query that would show me what procs, views, or functions are referencing the field? Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: DBA_SOURCE will give you function/procedure/package code. You can make a string search on the line column.

Comment: To search all view code, to my best knowledge you have to create a new table with a convertion of the text column of dba_views: create table viewtext as select owner,view_name,to_lob(text) text from dba_views. You can then search the text column in viewtext for a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Oracle are you using?  If you are using at least 11.1, which introduced column-level dependency tracking, and you're not afraid to leverage some undocumented data dictionary tables, you can [create a `dba_dependency_columns` view](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/10/dbadependencycolumns.html) that will give you this information.  But that will show every piece of code that depends on that column not just those where the column is used in the `WHERE` clause of a statement.

You can search `dba_source` for the text of procedures, functions, and triggers to look for code that has that sort of `WHERE` clause.  That gets a little tricky, though-- if someone put the list of values on a different line or if there is an inline view where that column name is aliased to something else, it can be tricky to find via a text search.  For views, you'd need to use `dbms_metadata` to generate the DDL for the view and search that in a loop.

Comment: The dba_source worked for the most part. But like you said, it's a little tricky.  Since we have the procs stored as actual files in SVN, I'll probably see if there is a way to search the text of the files for the values.  Thank you for your answers though, it definitely helped and are good references for future needs.